# Desiging a PHP user login system

Tags: php, authentication, system

So I am looking to design a high security php user system. I have decided to begin at the login/session end. I would like someone to take a look at my plan and inform me of loopholes and security flaws.

This is my first time attempting to create a system on such a level, if you find a problem could you send me resources to help me fix it.

Connecting to the database
*I will be using MYSQL so it's your standard database connect stored in a file outside of the sites root.

Registration 
*The registration will be a simple form, I am using a function stored in a external file to sanitize the input and protect from SQL Injection

```
// A function to sanitize input for data being input into a database
function sanitizeinput($rawinput) {
$sanitizedinput = mysql_real_escape_string($rawinput);
return $sanitizedinput;
}
```

Is there anything I need on this function to secure it up any more?

The password is the to be hashed using either SHA-512 or BCrypyt, I have done a little research and have seen a lot of people saying MD5 is no longer secure enough, I want to ensure the best security possible so what should I use to hash the passwords.

I have also added a randomly generated salt using the following snippet, which this appended to the front of the hashed password and then rehashed. The salt is then stored in the database in plain text format should I be thinking of encrypting this for extra security?

When a user goes to log in their entered password will be hashed, the salt from the database added and rehashed and then compared to the password stored in the database.

If the password matches a session will be created that will then be locked to a single IP address and user agent. The session will then expire after a short time. The session will only be used to store a login token, the username and password will of course not be store in the session.

When the user logs in the token will be stored into the database with a username assigned to it, so that we can safely pull the users details from the database using the token, without the risk storing it in the session.

If the password is incorrect the user will not be logged in... duh, I will enforce a brute force protection on this too, after three attempts the users IP and User Agent will be locked out for 15 mins and after ten failed attempts blocked in the firewall.

I feel like I am forgetting something, but I can't put my finger directly upon it.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use any hashing algorithm natively, make sure to use a salt for extra security and to help prevent hackers from using rainbow tables to reverse your hash.

Comment: a single ip is not good enough..consider me.. i use dial up dynamic ip for my laptop, so every time my ip changes..i have to login again..nope

Comment: http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice

Comment: First thing, if you want it to be secure, don't use the mysql API, use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/introducing-passwordlib.html

Answer (score 2):

I am by no means an expert on this but first off switch to PDO for connecting to mySQL. It seems a little more difficult but protects you 100% from anyone trying to do sql injections IF USED PROPERLY. For encryption I used this to generate a random salt per user:

```
    function generateSalt($length, $chars)
{
  $randString = '';
  $charLength = strlen($chars);
  for($count = 0; $count < $length; $count++)
  {
    $randString .= substr($chars, mt_Rand(0, ($charLength-1)), 1);
  }
  return $randString;
}
```

If you feed it a string it spits out a given length salt from the characters in that string. Then I believe I used blowfish due to the fact that it is not easy to crack.

Did you consider XSS vulnerabilities? I have not yet and need to get on that. Make sure users aren't injecting html or javascript code into your database that might be displayed somewhere on the page later.

Good luck.

EDIT:
Here is what I use for "hashing"

```
$cryptOptions = '$2y$10$' . $salt . '$';
$hashedPassword = crypt($password1, $cryptOptions);
```

Comment: Wait... Why can I only comment on my own...

Comment: I am going to switch to PDO. What about securing sessions, any ideas?

Comment: For securing sessions I have heard IP's however the issue is that if a persons IP switches it logs then out. That isn't the best solution but it does protect from session hijacking. Truthfully there is no foolproof way. The best way is to update some kind of cookie and if the person talking to the server has an incorrect "code" in their cookie it logs them out. This way if the cookie is stolen then it logs the attacker and the real user out if the real user tries to do something. You could go a step further and maybe maintain a connection with ajax or something? These are only ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you store the salt within the databse? Let's assume someone gets access to your database - he will have the passwords and salt(s). If you had your salt hardcoded or somewhere else he would just have the hashed passwords. If the attacker gets full access to your systems this doesn't matter whatsoever.

Also, will you use https for the login precedure?

Assuming you have more than one database connection and they have different encodings - you should pass the correct link to your sanitizer function. By the way, what's the benefit of wrapping mysql_real_escape_string with another function that doesn't add a thing (but actually limits the actual function)?
I'd encourage you to use PDO.

Comment: Hardcoding a salt wouldn't help, especially if the salt is a fixed string this would mean that two users using the same password would result in having the same hash in the db. So if someone is able to get access to your db, he could guess passwords by simple checking whether the most frequent hash would map to the most frequent password used (e.g. "password", "god" or "12345").

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a similar prototype few months ago in Java.

From what I see it looks quite similar to what I had. Some things that I have done (or at least planneed to do), which I don't see from you explanation

1. Obviously secure the HTTP channel with TLS, otherwise you would be sending your password in plaintext.
2. Use some key streching functions such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2, so that brute force attacks would be even more computation intensive.
3. I applied the hash several times. (I used 1024 iterations), again to protect against brute force attacks. If I would have to do it again, I would rather spend time implementing 2.
4. Sessions should expire on a last-accessed-time basis.

Hope that gives you some additional ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies I cannot comment on m02ph3u5's post so I have to post another answer. Storing salts in the database is completely standard. The reason that salts exist is to prevent brute forcing with rainbow tables. Rainbow tables are precomputed hashes which would allow all the passwords in the database to be cracked quickly. With salts, even ones known to the attacker, a rainbow table cannot be precomputed. This means people have to brute force each password. This is good because if you use an algorithm like blowfish then cracking hundreds of passwords becomes impractical.

It isn't a way to make passwords impossible to crack. It is a way to make it impractical to crack ALL the passwords.

EDIT: If they gain access to your db they will have only your hashed password and salts. They still require the plain text password.

EDIT2: So the idea is they have access to the site so the only thing we want to do at that point is protect the password. Usually people re-use passwords. Hashing is really just to protect those kinds of people.

Comment: So should I encrypt the salt? I am guessing no it wouldn't add anything on a security level. With the thought in mind that it's to make rainbow table attacks useless in retrieving a database of passwords would it better protect a single password? Yes?

Comment: No it would just add an extra layer. If you want to make it harder to crack the passwords just use blowfish with more iterations. The idea is to protect all the passwords as a whole since protecting every single one is impossible if the attacker is bent on cracking them. Of course you can do so many iterations that every single one becomes impractical to crack however then your website will take a while to authenticate users.